# Data Truncation on SBS2008

Tags: java, powershell, truncate

I am trying to read events from the event log of two windows machines. One is Windows 10 Enterprise (works perfectly) and one is Small Business Server 2008. On the SBS2008 machine output is truncated at the 78th character but I can’t see why.

This is the powershell command that I am running:

```
get-eventlog Application -After (Get-Date).AddDays(-10)  |
Where-Object {$_.EntryType  -like 'Error' -or $_.EntryType -like
'Information'} |  Format-Table  -Property TimeGenerated, Index,
EventID, EntryType, Source, Message -autosize | Out-String -Width 4000
```

It performs fine in a powershell edit window on both machines, no truncation. 
If I run it in a command window using powershell -file GetEvents.ps1 the output is truncated:
C:\BITS>powershell -file GetEvents.ps1
[image]

I cannot work out what is doing this. This is the Java code:

```
String command = "powershell.exe  " + Cmd;
Process powerShellProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
powerShellProcess.getOutputStream().close();
String line;
BufferedReader stdout = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(powerShellProcess.getInputStream()));
while ((line = stdout.readLine()) != null) {
    if (line.length() > 0) {
        System.out.println(line);
    }
}
```

Can anyone suggest a better way to get the events out of the log or suggest how I read the output from the powershell script without it being broken up by carriage returns? This was quite disappointing as I had tested it extensively on my machine (the W10 one) only to find it fails on the SBS2008 customer machine!
I have checked the libraries and java versions used on the different machines and they are the same. It’s not the println statement because I do some parsing of the string within the final ‘While’ block and the incoming line is definitely truncated.

I have subsequently tried using Get-winevent but when I put a filterhashtable flag on the command it fails when run on SBS2008 saying 'the parameter is incorrect' (works fine on W10).
My ideal would be able to get all the events from a specific logfile since a given eventID (because I can store that) but it seems to be virtually impossible to get the same output across all windows operating systems in the same format. Any suggestions welcome.

Comment: `| Format-Table | Out-String`.  "I mix the cake batter, put it in the oven, then take the finished cake out of the oven, put it back in the cake mixer, and then mash it back into the cake tin, but now it's all crumbs. I don't get it?" Format-Table is for end-of-pipeline display to an admin in a console session, and approximately nothing else. It will throw away data to make a nicer table. Once Format-Table has tried to break up the data to show it on a host that doesn't exist inside Java, all the Out-String -width 4000 will never put it back together again.

Comment: Can you read JSON or CSV in you Java, then format it there?

Comment: Thanks for this, it makes perfect sense, however, it leaves me with a problem... When I take the Format-Table out I can get the full string but it does not include the EventID column which is crucial for me. How do I get the command to include that column without using format-table?

Answer (score 0):

The answer for SBS2008 is here; http://www.mcbsys.com/blog/2011/04/powershell-get-winevent-vs-get-eventlog/
SBS2008 cannot use a hashtable, must use filterxml. Unfortunately when I use filterxml on SBS2008 it does not return the error message, everything else, just no the message. This is using the prescribed method of cutting and pasting the XML query from Event Viewer (https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2011/04/14/using-get-winevent-filterxml-to-process-windows-events/).
After more research I have come up with a script which does (sort of) what I want. It lacks the eventindex (which is a shame) but it consistently returns the events from the System & Application eventlogs:

```
$fx = '<QueryList>
  <Query Id="0" Path="Application">
    <Select Path="Application">*[System[(Level=1  or Level=2 or Level=3) and TimeCreated[timediff(@SystemTime) &lt;= 43200000]]]</Select>
  </Query>
</QueryList>'
function Set-Culture([System.Globalization.CultureInfo] $culture) { [System.Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = $culture ; [System.Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = $culture } ; Set-Culture en-US ; get-winevent -FilterXml $fx | out-string -width 470

$fx = '<QueryList>
  <Query Id="0" Path="System">
    <Select Path="System">*[System[(Level=1  or Level=2 or Level=3) and TimeCreated[timediff(@SystemTime) &lt;= 43200000]]]</Select>
  </Query>
</QueryList>'
Set-Culture en-US ; get-winevent -FilterXml $fx | out-string -width 470
```

I hope that this is useful to someone else!